# How to implement dfu-programmer for Atmel in Android

Tags: android, atmel, dfu

I am developing a native Android app which talks to a cortex (microcontroller) which has Atmel micro-controller inside. I found  command-line programmer for Atmel (https://dfu-programmer.github.io/) for Linux and Windows but I do not know how to implement this in my android application. I am new to such concept (DFU integration), so not even sure how to start it.

Can anyone please help? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? How do you expect your app to talk to the atmel microcontroller? Are you using bluetooth, HTTP, a custom protocol, or something else?

Comment: I am doing this with usb connection. So, my android device is in host mode.